# currentTarget.name and gotoAndPlay AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am very new to this and I am trying to combine currentTarget.name and gotoAndPlay which does not work. Can someone please help me, I want to play the symbol I click on, but I can't just write ball1.gotoAndPlay(2);, because there are 3 movieclips. I want to play the one I click on.

```
ball1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, trykkFunksjon);
ball2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, trykkFunksjon);
ball3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, trykkFunksjon);

function trykkFunksjon(evt)
{
    if (mineTall.length < 7)
    {
        var innTall = evt.currentTarget.name.split("ball");;
        trace(int(innTall[1]));
        mineTall.push(int(innTall[1]));
    }
    else
    {
        txtOutput.text = "Du kan ikke gjette flere tall";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evt.currentTarget` will refer to the `MovieClip` that was clicked. So you can call `gotoAndPlay` on it directly without getting the name.

`(evt.currentTarget as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay(2);`

Comment: Or `MovieClip(evt.currentTarget).gotoAndPlay(2);`

Comment: Can you help me once again? Sorry for asking.